# How to Delete Multiple Files Inside Multiple Zip Files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04

Currently I am doing the following command to delete a file inside a zip file on my server:

```
zip -d file.zip .exe
```

But I have so many zip file that needs to delete all files with an **.exe** file extension.

All the zip files is stored under "downloads" folder.

Is it possible to delete files from multiple zip file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` and `xargs`:

```
find -iname '*.zip' -print0|xargs -0 -i zip -d '{}' .exe
```

or to specify the directory explicitly:

```
find /downloads -iname '*.zip' -print0|xargs -0 -i zip -d '{}' .exe
```

**EDIT:** To exclude a specific directory, `/downloads/admin`:

```
find /downloads -path /downloads/admin -prune -o -iname '*.zip' -print0|xargs -0 -i zip -d '{}' .exe
```

Comment: Even simpler, you could use `-exec` instead of `find | xargs`

Comment: Hi, Sorry I forgot that inside the downloads folder, there are several folders that is created based on who uploaded that .zip file. So an example is /downloads/user1, /downloads/user2, /downloads/user3, etc. Is the first or second code you gave above still valid?

Comment: @user176890 yes, it searches in all subdirectories recursively, to unlimited depth.

Comment: Thank you. I tried and it works. I have one more question which I forgot to ask. Is it possible to exclude a folder? Example I want to exclude the folder called "admin" inside downloads folder. Because I can assure that admin folder don't have .exe file that is infected with a virus because it's my account.

Comment: @user176890 I edited my answer to add that.

Comment: Thanks. Can I also use this: `find -path admin -iname '*.zip' -print0|xargs -0 -i zip -d '{}' .exe`. Since I'm already in the root directory of "downloads" folder.

Comment: @user176890 it's actually `find -path ./admin -prune -o -iname '*.zip' -print0|xargs -0 -i zip -d '{}' .exe` in that case