# Delete specific file name in multiple ZIP files

Tags: unix, shell, zip, find

I have around 800 zip files. I following this question to delete file inside every file.
[How to Delete Multiple Files Inside Multiple Zip Files?](https://superuser.com/questions/685504/how-to-delete-multiple-files-inside-multiple-zip-files)

I tried

```
find /myfolder -iname '*.zip' -print0|xargs -0 -i zip -d photo1.jpg
```

But it does return with error

```
xargs: zip: No such file or directory
```

I am sure I put files in the correct directory. Can anyone help me with this?

Much appreciate with your answer.
Thanks,

Comment: Is zip installed on your computer? The error seems to say you don't have the zip command

Comment: That exactly the point. I just checked that zip not yet install on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
find /myfolder -iname '*.zip' -exec zip -d {} photo1.jpg \;
```

Notes:

1. The general `-print0/xargs` approach is good but find's `-exec` option eliminates the need for a pipeline.
2. The name of the zip file needs to be before the name of the file to delete.

If you prefer the pipeline, try:

```
find /myfolder -iname '*.zip' -print0 | xargs -0 -i zip -d {} photo1.jpg
```

Or, since `-i` is deprecated:

```
find /myfolder -iname '*.zip' -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} zip -d {} photo1.jpg
```

#### Deleting files from a zip's subdirectories

The above commands will only delete `photo1.jpg` if it is in the root directory of the zip file.  To delete `photo1.jpg` from any and all subdirectories inside the zip:

```
find /myfolder -iname '*.zip' -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} zip -d {} '*/photo1.jpg'
```

Notes:

1. For reliable results when using a wildcard like `*`, it is important to put the file name inside quotes so that the glob is passed directly to zip.  Otherwise, there is a risk the shell may find a match and do pathname expansion before the name is handed to `zip`.
2. There is big difference between `/*photo1.jpg` and `*/photo1.jpg`.  The former will result in the deletion of all files whose names end with `photo1.jpg`.  This includes file names such as `abcphoto1.jpg`.  The latter will only delete files actually named `photo1.jpg`.

Comment: I tried you second and third options. But still no luck. The same output I got:
`xargs: zip: No such file or directory`

Comment: You said that The name of the zip file needs to be before the name of the file to delete.
But this script suppose to find every zip inside the folder and then find the specific file in *zip and delete it, right?

Comment: I also tried this command but it return: 
`find: zip': No such file or directory`

Comment: @SambathDreamHigh I just copied and pasted all three from the answer to my terminal and they all work for me.  The only way that I have found to reproduce the error that you show is to run a command like `find zip -iname '*.zip' -print0 ...` when there is no directory named `zip`.  Please provide me with more details on precisely what you are doing.  (Also, what OS and shell are you using?)

Comment: I tried with my MacBook and that does the job. I got error with  my Ubuntu 14.04.
Thanks so much for your time and great answer.

Comment: I just found the problem. The method work well with the file in the zip root directory. But it's work with the file inside the folder in the zip. 
It's work with  `myzip.zip/Photo1.jpg`
And it's not work with  `myzip.zip/folder/Photo1.jpg`

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the final solution to this problem. The command below will delete all the file in zip and its all sub-directories with the specific file name.

```
find /myfolder -iname '*.zip' -print0 | xargs -0 -i zip -d {} /*photo1.jpg
```

Just add `/*`before file name to delete specific file or `/*.extension` to delete all files with that extension.