# Append a file to a bunch of *.zip files in a folder

Tags: unix, shell, zip, find

I need to append a file to a bunch of zip files in a folder.
I tried the command:

```
zip -r myfile.zip photo.jpg
```

But this only add the file to specific zip file. How do I make it loop. find and add to every zip in the folder?

Much appreciate for the answer.

Regards,

Comment: Except for `-d` <--> `-r`, this appears to be a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/1112688/delete-specific-file-name-in-multiple-zip-files

Comment: @John1024  Great. Thank for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the find command with the exec flag.

`find . -type f -name "*.zip" -exec zip {} -r photo.jpg \;`

Disclaimer: Written from memory, not sure it is exactly right. But it's a place to start.